Estimate the probability that a crack length exceeds a threshold value after N cycles
The length $a$ of a crack after $N$ fatigue cycles $N$ is
$$a(N;C,m) = \left(a_0^{\left(1-\frac m 2\right)}+ C\left(1-\frac m 2\right)B^mN\right)^{\frac{2}{2-m}}$$
where $a_0$ is the initial crack length, $B$ is a value which depends on the range of stresses applied during a fatigue cycle, and $C$ and $m$ are unknown model parameters. We have a dataset $D$ of iid measurements $D=(N_i, a_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ ($n$ is the number of measurements, not to be confused with the number of cycles $N$), where, for fixed $a_0$ and $B$, each time we perform a different number of fatigue cycles $N_i$ and we measure the corresponding final crack length $a_i$.
The goal of the analysis is to estimate the number of cycles $N_c$ such that the probability $Pr\left(a(N;C,m)>a_c\right)$ is equal to a threshold value $p_c$. We work in a Bayesian framework, so we assume Gaussian priors $\ln{C}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_C, \sigma_C)$, $m\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_m, \sigma_m)$ for the model parameters, and measurements errors $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{\epsilon})$. In other words, we assume that the likelihood $\mathcal{L}(D|C,m)$ of the data $D$ under our crack growth model is
$$\mathcal{L}(D|C,m)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma_{\epsilon}^2)^{n/2}}e^{-SS/2\sigma_{\epsilon}^2}$$
where the residual sum of squares is
$$SS=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-a(N_i;C,m))^2 $$
How can I estimate $N_c$?
A possible solution (if I'm not forgetting something important) could be to:

use MCMC to compute the posterior distribution of random parameters $C, m$ $$p(C,m|D)=\frac{\mathcal{L}(D|C,m)p(C)p(m)}{\int\mathcal{L}(D|C,m)p(C)p(m)dCdm}$$
sample $C_i, m_i$ from $p(C,m|D)$ (actually, MCMC generates samples from $p(C,m|D)$, so I already have such samples from step 1)
substitute the samples $C_i,m_i$ into $a(N;C,m)$, for an array of values $N_j=0,\dots,N_{max}$. For each $N_j$, I thus have a set of samples $a_{ij}=a(N_j;C_i,m_i)$
for each value $N_j$ I estimate $Pr\left(a(N;C,m)>a_c\right)$ as $\frac{\#(a_{ij}>a_c)}{\#a_{ij}}$, i.e., the number of samples $a_{ij}>a_c$ divided by the total number of samples $a_{ij}$ (apologies if the notation is awkward/nonstandard: feel free to suggest improvements).
I estimate $N_c$ as the smallest $N_j$ such that $\frac{\#(a_{ij}>a_c)}{\#a_{ij}}>p_c$

However, I have two doubts:

This isn't really much of an estimate. Ideally, given a dataset $D$, a statistical estimation procedure of $N_c$ should return an estimated values as well as some measure of the estimation uncertainty. Here I just got a value for $N_c$. What am I missing?
for a series of reasons, I'd need to implement this in Python, and to have the whole procedure run really fast (ideally, a few seconds). It looks like MCMC can be slow even for these simple problems, so I was wondering if there could be an alternative way to sample from $p(C,m|D)$. I could compute the normalization factor $Z=\int\mathcal{L}(D|C,m)p(C)p(m)dCdm$ using the tensor product of two 1D Gauss-Hermite quadrature rules, similar to what it's illustrated here. However, how would I then sample from the posterior?


This is a very complicated problem. If it were my problem, I would separate it in two parts. The first part is to make dead sure that I am solving the right problem. And I would use Wolfram Mathematica to solve for a few examples - however long this may take (hours, days, ...). The second part is to improve the computational speed. And while developing the Python programming to make dead sure to obtain exactly the same solutions as before. Finally, for the Bayesian approach to be effective, the prior probabilities have to reflect the engineering background knowledge. Good luck with it.

As I understand $C \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_C, ,  \sigma_C)$ and $m \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_m, , \sigma_m)$. Also in the notations $a_c$ and $N_c$ the index "c" seem to refer to "critical" and has nothing to do with $C$. If so maybe another notation could be used?

I think also that the use of $i$ both for the observation number and the MCMC iterate index is misleading. Maybe use $C^{[k]}$ and $m^{[k]}$?

Do you consider $m$ and $C$ to be fixed values that are the same for each of the $n$ measurements or are they random effects that vary for different measurements? E.g. is it like the crack length (as function of $N$) is every time following a different curve, or is it following the same curve for different cracks. Currently you seem to be modelling it as a fixed effect and the only randomness is from iid noise $\epsilon$. (to me this seems a bit unnatural, I would imagine that you get a correlation between crack lengths due to a random effect in the parameters $m$ and $C$)

$Pr\left(a(N;C,m)>a_c\right)$ in which sense should I consider this probability? I can consider it as a model parameter, and for a given $m$, $B$ and $C$ we can compute this probability which is based on the randomness in the $a_i$. I can also consider it in terms of the posterior probability distribution and consider the $N_C$ for which the we have a posterior probability of $p_c$ that $a(N;C,m)>a_c$.

Do you have measurements with different $B$?

Is it possible to use a linear approximation to the crack length function, or are you having measurements in a non-linear domain? Also if $m$ is close to $2$ then the function is approximately an exponential function.

Since your model allows a non-zero probability of a negative crack length, you should seriously consider an alternative model that applies the normally distributed error term to the log-crack-length instead of the untransformed crack-length.

@Ben if it is noise for 'measurements errors' then it is realistic to have potentially negative observations. Probably a more strong concern is the fact that these cracks are modeled to behave deterministically with only the measurements as error.

@SextusEmpiricus the crack length is following a different curve for different cracks, but for a given crack and different $N$, we assume it's following the same curve, though of course measurements will never fall on a single curve because of measurement error.

@SextusEmpiricus Re: $Pr\left(a(N;C,m)>a_c\right)$, I don't understand how it could be a model parameter. For me the only sensible interpretation is in terms of posterior probability, which is why I introduced the posterior pdf or $C$ and $m$ given $D$ in order to compute it.

@SextusEmpiricus "Do you have measurements with different $B$". Yes, 10 sets of data, each one for a different $B$. $B$ is easy to control to a high level of accuracy during experiments.

@SextusEmpiricus re: linear approximation, you mean in a log-log scale? In the original scale, a linear approximation would be totally useless. Re: $m$, values of $m$ lower than 3 (or to be more precise, a posterior distribution of $m$ with a non-negligible probability mass in the region $m$<3) would make me discard the fit at once. So $m$ is not close to $2$.

@Ben the probability of a negative crack length is negligible given the data, so applying the errors to the log-length is a useless complication.  When the probability of a negative crack is O(10^(-100)), it has zero relevance to the actual statistical analysis. But I did make a mistake with the prior distribution for $C$, which is on $\ln{C}$ and not $C$ itself.

@DeltaIV I completely misinterpretated the sign of the coefficients in the power, so it is negative. I thought you would have something like an approximate exponential growth which could be approximately linear for small percentage of crack length increase.

"the crack length is following a different curve for different cracks" this requires random effects which is not currently in your model. You have a prior, but that's different.

@SextusEmpiricus yeah, the formula is very annoying in a sense. It's true that the exponent is negative, but at the same time it's also true that the coefficient of $N$ inside the round brackets is negative, so...

"I don't understand how it could be a model parameter." If you have a model that includes randomness for the crack length evolution, than you can translate the model parameters into a probability. For example if we gave some variable $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then instead by using $\sigma$ as parameter, we can also use $P[X>1]$ as parameter.

@SextusEmpiricus "you have a prior, which is different". Interesting. Sampling from the posterior distribution does generate a different curve each time. Thus, I'm not sure why having a prior is not enough.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@DeltaIV your C and m are physical constant and what the prior and posterior express about it is not a variation in the population (like every crack having a different C or m) but instead they express your uncertainty about the unknown constants. E.g. if you analyse light speed in a Bayesian framework then you will have a posterior for the light speed, but that doesn't mean that the light speed is considered different each experiment.

@SextusEmpiricus the light speed example was "illuminating" :-) Ok, let's consider C and m as physical constants and not as random effects. I had a quick look at the literature on crack growth, and it looks like everyone considers C and m physical constants which only depend on the material and the casting procedure (both fixed in my dataset). The random effects model sounds interesting, but let's leave it for another question.

@DeltaIV currently you model randomness as measurement noise, but couldn't it be that every test subject has slightly different C and m and that is causing random variations in measurd values? Do you measure the same test subject repeatedly, in between the several cycles? Of do you not have such within subject measurements? If you do have such data, how do the curves look like? Do the measurements within a subject mainly have measurement noise or mainly variations in the position of the entire curve?

If you measure after each cycle, then it becomes very interesting to model only the changes, since possibly you have a correlation in the error of the crack growth (an initial big growth will cause all subsequent sizes to be big). The growth could be a bit like a random walk.

As I understand the formula at the top of the OP gives the expected
length which depends on the parameters $C$ and $m$, whereas $a_0$ and
$B$ are known quantities. I will denote by $A$ the random crack length
and by $\mu_A$ or $\mu_A(N \,\vert\,C,\,m)$ the regression mean. Note
that it is essential that $m < 2$. If so, $\mu_A$ is a strictly
increasing function of $N$ for given $C$ and $m$, with the reciprocal
function given by
\begin{equation}
  \tag{1}
  N = \frac{\mu_A^{1 - m/2} - a_0^{1 - m /2}}{1 - m/2} \, \frac{1}{C B ^m} =: 
  \nu(\mu_A \, \vert \,C,\,m).
\end{equation}
Maybe  the limit for $m \approx 2$ can be used for $m=2$.
From the form of the likelihood, the model is actually a Gaussian
non-linear regression with $2$ parameters $C$, $m$ and the error
variance $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ seems to be considered as known.
If a crack length $a^\star$ and a probability $p^\star$ are given one
can, for any given $C$ and $m$, find the value $N^\star(C,\,m)$ such
that $F_{A}(a^\star,\,N^\star \vert\, C,\, m) = 1 - p^\star$ where
$F_A(a,\,N\, \vert\, C,\, m) := \text{Pr}\{A \leqslant a \vert\, C,\,
m\}$ which depends on $N$. Indeed the corresponding expectation of $A$
is then
$$
  \mu_A(N^\star \, \vert \, C,\, m) 
   = a^\star - \sigma_\epsilon \,q_Z(1- p^\star)
$$
where $q_Z$ is the quantile function of the standard normal. Hence
\begin{equation}
  \tag{2}
  N^\star(C,\,m)
   = \nu\left\{a^\star - \sigma_\epsilon \,q_Z(1- p^\star) \, \vert \, C,\,m\right\}
\end{equation}
where the function $\nu$ is given by (1).
As an interesting feature of the Bayesian framework, the so-called
predictive (posterior) distribution of the crack length $A$ after
$N$ cycles is obtained by "marginalizing out" $C$ and $m$
\begin{equation}
  \tag{3}
  F_A(a;\,N) = \iint F_A(a;\, N \, \vert \, C,\, m)\,p(C,\,m \, \vert \, D) 
  \,\text{d}C \, \text{d}m.
\end{equation}
While $F_A(a;\, N \, \vert \, C,\, m)$ is a Gaussian distribution with
mean $\mu_A(N \, \vert \, C,\, m)$ and variance $\sigma_\epsilon^2$, the
distribution $F_A(a;\,N)$ is an over-dispersed version of the
Gaussian. It may be heavy-tailed.
Since $N^\star$ is a known function of the parameter $[C,\, m]$ its
posterior distribution can be retrieved from that of the
parameter. One can give a credible interval on $N^\star$.  Yet it
makes sense to find instead the value $N^\circ$ such that
$F_{A}(a^\star,\,N^\circ) = 1 - p^\star$, hence using the predictive
distribution. This value is computed in the OP. It better assesses the
risk related to a large crack since it takes into account the
uncertainty on the parameters, the predictive distribution being more
over-dispersed when the posterior is looser.
To see how the two notions differ, suppose that $K$ nearly independent
MCMC iterates $[C^{[k]}, \, m^{[k]}]$ are available.

One can approximate the posterior distribution of $N^\star(C,\,m)$
by the empirical distribution of the values $N^\star(C^{[k]},
  m^{(k]})$ as computed by (2).

By contrast, to find $N^\circ$ one has to use an approximation
of (3)
$$
      \widetilde{F}_A(a;\,N) :=  \frac{1}{K} \,
     \sum_{k} F_{\texttt{norm}}(a; \mu_A^{[k]}, \, \sigma_\epsilon), \qquad
  \mu_A^{[k]} := \mu_A(N,\, C^{[k]}, \, m^{[k]}).
  $$
One can use this approximation for $a := a^\star$ and each $N$ in a grid of
possible values, then solve approximately
$\widetilde{F}_{A}(a^\star,\,N^\circ)
  = 1 - p^\star$.


Note that in the first computation one does not need to use empirical
quantiles since the distribution of $A$ conditional on $C$ and $m$ is
known. The second "predictive" approach is the one used in the OP. It
does not need a credible interval which is the "first doubt". Yet
the estimation uncertainty is accounted for in the result.
The cheapest alternative to MCMC would rely on the computation of the
posterior mode, say $[\widehat{C}, \, \widehat{m}]$ and use Laplace's
approximation. This should easily be implemented in a language like
Python. Gauss-Hermite quadrature rules can indeed do better. Since the
parameter is only bi-dimensional, a quadrature can also be used to get
the joint posterior density $p(C,\,m \,\vert \,D)$ on a grid of say
1e4 nodes. For instance the bi-dimensional Simpson's rule should work
well to get the normalizing constant. Then, for the first computation
a simple weighted mean of $N^\star(C,\, m)$ given by (2) can be used
to get the posterior mean. For the second (predictive) approach
$F_A(a^\star, \,N)$ can be evaluated by using the approximation of (3)
obtained by quadrature on a grid of candidate values for $N$. In both
cases one does not need to sample from the posterior. Yet in the first
computation, getting a credible interval on $N^\star$ would require
more work.  Of course the log-sum exponential trick must be
used. The limitation is that using an extra unknown parameter such as
$\sigma_{\epsilon}$ would be a pain.
Anyway, an efficient MCMC sampler such as Stan should be used to
investigate the posterior before choosing a suitable
approximation. Non-Gaussian priors should be used for $C$ and $m$ to
cope with the constraints $C >0$ and $m<2$.
EDIT The condition $m< 2$ is actually not required, because
$\mu_A(N)$ turns out to be an increasing function of $N$ even when
$m > 2$ with the reciprocal function (1) above. However the quantity
for which a non-integer exponent $2/(2-m)$ is taken should be
positive so
$$
   a_0 + C \,\frac{2 -m}{2}\,\left[ \sqrt{a_0} B \right]^m N > 0
$$
must hold for the range of values of interest for $N$. This may impact
the choice of the prior for $C$ and $m$.

$m$ is >3 for all meaningful fits (or to be a nitpicker: $Pr(m<3|D)\approx 0$, so the assumption $m<2$ is out of the question.

I mean, sure, in principle if you had just a really small ($n<5$, maybe?) or very noisy dataset, the posterior distribution might be so wide that $Pr(m<3|D)$ would not negligible. Luckily, this is not the case.

@DeltaIV Oh yes, the $N \mapsto a$ is increasing also for $m > 2$ So my remark about the condition $m < 2$ is irrelevant at least if $B>0$ and $C>0$..Anyway I think that this does not change anything else to my answer. I should edit my answer.
